# Display only one field from an embedded document with MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm a real beginner with MongoDB and MongoID.
I created two scaffolds

```
class Objet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :nom, type: String

  embeds_one :coordonnee
end
```

And

```
class Coordonnee
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :adresse1, type: String
  field :adresse2, type: String
  field :code_postal, type: String
  field :ville, type: String

  embedded_in :objet
end
```

That's what I get when creating a new `Objet` :

[image: Objet document]

Now, I'm trying to show only the field `adresse1` for this document, but it doesn't work. I can display only the whole embedded document doing this :

When I do :

```
<%= @objet.coordonnees.adresse1 %>
```

I get this error :

```
undefined method `adresse1' for #<Hash:0x2b2b1f0>
```

How can I do that ?

EDIT

Doing that, I can display all the elements "Adresse1, adresse2, ville, code_postal" :

```
 Controller

 def show
    @objet = Objet.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @objet }
    end
  end

View

<%= @objet.nom %>
   <% @objet.coordonnee.each do |t|  %>  
    <%= t[1] %>
  <% end %>
```

But my question is : How to display ONLY one of them ? Such as ville, or code_postal or adresse1... ?

Answer (score 0):

Not hugely familiar with MongoID, but assuming you can make calls straight to mongo, there is a second implicit parameter to all find-like statements called a `projection` that specifies what exactly you would like to return.

For instance, showing only `adresse1` for all items in your collection:

```
db.collection.find({},{"coordonnees.adresse1": 1, "_id":0})
```

should return only the `adresse1` parameter. I wasn't quite able to tell exactly what context you're displaying the objects in, but regardless of context, api calls to mongo should be fairly straightforward to make. Let me know if I've misinterpreted this question though.

In your posted example, you should change your find function to something like the following:

```
Objet.find({params[:id]}, {:fields => [coordonnees.adresse1]})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. How can I translate this `db.collection.find({},{"adresse1": 1})` in show.html.erb ?

Answer (score 0):

What was your code that works for the full document? It was dropped from your post.

In the mongo Shell, you could do this with dot notation `db.collection.find({},{'coordonnees.adresse1':1,'_id':0})` You need to specify the `'_id':0` because `_id` is always returned by default.

The other answer will not work because `adresse1` is a subdocument. You must include the reference to `coordonnees`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I made a slight typo, but I would prefer it as a comment than a jab in a different answer...

Comment: Also you mean collection.find, collectionfind doesn't exist. Constructive criticism yo.

Comment: Sorry @SlaterTyranus, I would have preferred to comment on your answer, but I don't have sufficient karma here to do so. You posted your answer while I was typing mine up - if I'd seen it first I'd have avoided the question entirely.

Comment: ah, totally forgot about that rep thing, bummer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.
To display only one element of the hash, I can do :

```
<%= @objet.coordonnees['adresse1'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using `embeds_one` or `embeds_many` as you are using singular and plural forms of the relation name interchangeably in your question.

If it is a `embeds_one` the problem is that you should not iterate on `@objet.coordonnee` as it is a single document. Your view code should look like:

```
<%= @objet.nom %>
<%= @objet.coordonnee.address1 %>
```

If it is a `embeds_many`, your relation name should be plural, then you should be able to use `t.address1` in your view.

```
# model Objet
embeds_many :coordonnees

# view
<%= @objet.nom %>
<% @objet.coordonnees.each do |t|  %>  
  <%= t.address1 %>
<% end %>
```